# Include Variable in S3 CP command for include block

Tags: aws, amazon-s3

I have a scenario where I want to include some files names in S3 cp command but it keeps failing.
Below is my command:-

```
DATE=$(date '+%Y%m%d')
/usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp "/test/copy" "s3://test-bucket/test/copy/" --include "TEST_$DATE.REQHE" --include "TEST_$DATE.ERRMSG_REQHE"
```

I am getting below error while running the command :-

```
upload failed: ./ to s3://test-bucket/test/copy/ [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/test/copy'
```

Can someone help me to modify the command so that it can work.

Output of manual commands :-

```
[root@server:/home/linux]$ /usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp /test/copy/ s3://test-bucket/test/copy/ --include "TEST_20211220.REQHE" --profile aws-s3 --sse aws:kms --sse-kms-key-id ab457654f-6562-43df-124l-4et75653bq12
upload failed: ../../test/copy to s3://test-bucket/test/copy/ [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/test/copy/'
[root@server:/home/linux]$ /usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp "/test/copy/" "s3://test-bucket/test/copy/" --include "TEST_20211220.REQHE" --profile aws-s3 --sse aws:kms --sse-kms-key-id ab457654f-6562-43df-124l-4et75653bq12
upload failed: ./../test/copy to s3://test-bucket/test/copy/ [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/test/copy/'
[root@server:/home/linux]$ /usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp "/test/copy" "s3://test-bucket/test/copy/" --include "TEST_20211220.REQHE" --profile aws-s3 --sse aws:kms --sse-kms-key-id ab457654f-6562-43df-124l-4et75653bq12
upload failed: ./../test/copy to s3://test-bucket/test/copy/ [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/test/copy/'
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @roaima I replaced the /test/copy with /test/copy/ as well but getting same error.
If I include the exact file name in the command works but I need to use that as a variable.
Can you replicate the command and try once.

Comment: @roaima I have added the output for manual commands in question. Pls check.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to think that adding the variable is the problem. Let's repeat your command but removing the variable and substituting today's date (20 December 2021):

```
/usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp "/test/copy" "s3://test-bucket/test/copy/" --include "TEST_20211220.REQHE" --include "TEST_20211220.ERRMSG_REQHE"
```

This command will almost certainly also fail in the same way (indeed, in the comments you confirmed this). We can therefore conclude that interpolation of the variable is irrelevant.

Look at the error message:

```
upload failed: […] [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/test/copy'
```

What this is telling you is that the path `/test/copy` is a directory, and that the Amazon `aws s3 cp` command will not copy directories. (It's not completely clear to me whether the error message is referring to the source or the target. Changing the name of one of them would resolve this ambiguity.) It doesn't matter whether you name the directory with or without a trailing slash; it's still a directory and the command won't copy directories.

The solution is not to copy a directory. Presumably the `aws s3 cp` command will copy files, but I do not have access to the command to test.

Comment: I replaced the /test/copy with /test/copy/ as well but getting same error. If I include the exact file name in the command works but I need to use that as a variable. Can you replicate the command and try once.

Comment: I have added the output for manual commands in question. Pls check.

Comment: @Ashmit please re-read the last paragraph. The variable isn't the problem!